# Is it possible to recover the conflict for a file after failing to resolve it correctly?

Tags: git, conflict, resolve

Assume I did a rebase and 100 files have conflicts. I have to resolve them one by one. Let us say I have resolved (N-1) files and I am working on the file N. After working on it for some time, I find I mess up the file. So I want to resolve it from scratch again. But I don't want to abort the rebase and do rebase again as I don't want to resolve the (N-1) files again.

Is it possible to recover the merge conflict for the file N only so I can resolve it again from scratch?

Comment: Are you using `git mergetool` or doing resolution by hand?

Comment: No matter what you use, it is always possible to mess up a file. Normally I do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file you are working on is named `test.txt`, and that the file had been left with conflict markers due to the merge attempt, and you've somehow botched doing the manual resolution of those conflicts, you can re-create the file with conflict markers with a few commands.

As background, it helps to know that, when a merge needs manual conflict resolution on a file, it leaves three different copies (called "stages") of that file in your `git` index. Stage 1 is a common ancestor of the two versions of the file being merged, and stages 2 and 3 are the two versions from the two branches you are trying to merge. Some, but not all, of the `git` utilities understand the syntax `:<stage>:<filename>` to reference these entries.

So, what you need to do first is to re-create temporary copies of these three files somewhere - I'll use `/tmp` here, but it's not mandatory:

```
git cat-file -p :1:test.txt > /tmp/test.txt.1
git cat-file -p :2:test.txt > /tmp/test.txt.2
git cat-file -p :3:test.txt > /tmp/test.txt.3
```

Then, use the `git` plumbing command `git merge-file` to recreate a file with the appropriate conflict markers. Note that the order of arguments is important here, and that it would probably be a good idea to save what work you've already done on this file in case you want to reference it in re-doing your merging.

```
mv test.txt test.txt.broken
git merge-file -p /tmp/test.txt.2 /tmp/test.txt.1 /tmp/test.txt.3 > test.txt
```

This will re-create `test.txt` with the conflict markers (although without the branch name comments that are typically included - if you really want those, you'll need to add some `-L <branchname>` arguments - you can type `git help merge-file` to get more information on that).

At that point, you can clean up the temporary files, and start over on resolving the conflicts in that file. Remember to `git add` it when you're done, and then continue with the rest of the files.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. If there are N files, I need to save 3N files. That is too expensive.

Comment: But I have an idea based on your solution.

Comment: Do this only for the file that is messed up:
git show :1:test.txt > /tmp/test.txt.1
git show :2:test.txt > /tmp/test.txt.2
git show :3:test.txt > /tmp/test.txt.3
git merge-file -p /tmp/test.txt.2 /tmp/test.txt.1 /tmp/test.txt.3 > test.txt

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - do that only for the file you're currently stuck on. Of course, you can repeat later if you get stuck on another file... the first N files that you've already handled, and hopefully the rest of them, you should be able to handle "normally", whatever that means...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for `git checkout --merge --`*`path/to/file`*.

Comment: No. Git checkout --merge does a three way merge for local changes. That is not what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: "When checking out paths from the index, this option lets you recreate the conflicted merge in the specified paths."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not so good a solution (looks like not so git'ish), but here is one possible way:

1. copy the (N - 1) files to a temp dir
2. git rebase --abort
3. copy the (N - 1) files back the git dir
4. work on your Nth file.

Comment: It takes O(N). Seems too expensive:)